# Google Spreadsheet to Calendar issue

Tags: calendar

Here is the script. It appears to run perfectly but when I go to press push to calendar I cannot seem to get it to work. I have tried a number of things and all have failed so far. Help would be greatly appreciated. Please and Thank you.

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
    var menuEntries = [ {name: "Add all to calendar", functionName: "pushToCalendar"} ];
    ss.addMenu("AutoCalendar", menuEntries);
}


//push new events to calendar
function pushToCalendar() {

    //spreadsheet variables
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('athomas12033@gmail.com')[0];
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()
    var updateRange = sheet.getRange('L1'); 
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var cellCol = cell.getColumn();
    var cellRow = cell.getRow();
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1,sheet.getLastRow(), 13);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var name = row[0];
        var type = row[3];
        var dateReq = row[4];
        var tstart = row[5];
        var tstop = row[6]; 
    }

    if (tstop == " ") {
        var tstop = tstart;
    }

    //show updating message
    updateRange.setFontColor('Blue');
    var title = row[7];
    if (title == " ") {
        var title = type;
        var narr = "";
    } else {
        var narr = row[8];
    }

    var meet = row[9];
    var realName = row[2];
    var contact = row[10];
    var appr = row[12];
    if (appr == "y") {
        cal.createEvent(title, new Date(dateReq+" "+tstart), new Date(dateReq+" "+tstop),                 
                {description:type+"\n"+narr+"\n"+realName+", "+contact,location:meet,guests:name,sendInvites:true});
    }     


    // Delete approved programs.
    for (var delRow = 1; delRow < numRows; delRow++) {
        var range = sheet.getRange(delRow,14,1,1);
        if (range.getValues() == "y") {
            sheet.deleteRow(delRow);
            var delRow = delRow-1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide the accompanying html and a more functional example.  Please feel free to build on this jsfiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/gd2q3gwq/

Comment: I am unsure what you mean in terms of a more functional example. I built this in the Google sheets script editor to run within the google docs environment.